# sonar.host.url not valid in end phase of C# plugin in SonarQube for Bamboo 1.17

Tags: c#, sonarqube, bamboo, sonar-runner

We updated our SonarQube for Bamboo plugin to the latest version, 1.17.0, and now our SQ integration is broken. No reports are sent to our Sonar Qube server. I get these errors in the Bamboo build output:

```
This setting is not valid in the "end" phase in this version of the C# plugin: sonar.host.url
Failing task since return code of [C:\sonar\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end /d:sonar.host.url=http://[ip-address]:9000/sonar /d:sonar.login=*** /d:sonar.password=*** was 1 while expected 0
```

And:

```
SONAR4BAMBOO: was not able to find a SonarQube result URL
```

It seems like somewhere in the process it's passing sonar.host.url as an argument to executing the runner, but in the latest SonarQube for Bamboo plugin this is, for some reason, not allowed anymore? Has anyone updated SonarQube for Bamboo and come up against similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the plug-in. We've just released a bug fix version 1.7.1 which only sets the sonar.login parameter in the MSBuild end task, thus resolving this issue.

Best regards,
Michael